# achieving login implementation without using sessions

Tags: session

Wordpress does not use sessions.

I always wondered what mechanism does WP use to maintain a user state when user goes from page to page?

Answer (score 13):

It uses bare cookies and stores the login state information client side.

[image]

## +

[image]

## =

> wordpress_7339a175323c25a8547b5a6d26c49afa=yourusername%7C1457109155%7C170f103ef3dc57cdb1835662d97c1e13;

## Where do all these cookies and salt come from?

The salt is in your wp-config.php file:

```
/**#@+
 * Authentication Unique Keys and Salts.
 *
 * Change these to different unique phrases!
 * You can generate these using the {@link https://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt/ WordPress.org secret-key service}
 * You can change these at any point in time to invalidate all existing cookies. This will force all users to have to log in again.
 *
 * @since 2.6.0
 */
define('AUTH_KEY',         'put your unique phrase here');
define('SECURE_AUTH_KEY',  'put your unique phrase here');
define('LOGGED_IN_KEY',    'put your unique phrase here');
define('NONCE_KEY',        'put your unique phrase here');
define('AUTH_SALT',        'put your unique phrase here');
define('SECURE_AUTH_SALT', 'put your unique phrase here');
define('LOGGED_IN_SALT',   'put your unique phrase here');
define('NONCE_SALT',       'put your unique phrase here');
```

### The unique phrases are used in a [cryptographic hash function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function)

The authentication cookie, the name of which is stored inside of AUTH_COOKIE, which is formed by concatenating “wordpress_” with the md5 sum of the siteurl set in default-constants.php. This is the default behavior and can be overridden from inside your configuration file, by setting up some of the constants upfront.

The authentication cookie a concatenation of the username, a timestamp until which the authentication cookie is valid., and an HMAC, which is sort of a key-biased hash for those who pulled of a TL;DR right now. The three variables are concatenated with the pipe character |.

Here is how the HMAC is constructed:

```
$hash = hash_hmac('md5', $username . '|' . $expiration, wp_hash($username . substr($user->user_pass, 8, 4) . '|' . $expiration, $scheme));
```

### Is this secure?

According to [this article](http://codeseekah.com/2012/04/09/why-wordpress-authentication-unique-keys-and-salts-are-important/) where most of the information in this answer came from it would take a hacker about week to brute force in sending 30 requests a second if they knew what your unique phrase was and 200,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000 times harder if your keys are unique.

Comment: Chris. Isn't sessions do exactly the same? Sessions require a cookie on the client site and server uses that to identify which user it is dealing with. I do not see what the difference is between a session based implementation  and this.

Comment: I am suddenly hungry.

Comment: PHP Sessions store and track login information inside the $_SESSION super global.  A session expires when you close your browser.  The WordPress Auth cookie lasts for much longer days or even weeks.  See: http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp/10/1/0

Answer (score 0):

Cookies are just the client-side storage of session data...
[WordPress Cookies](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Cookies)

In fact, one can have cookies without sessions, but no sessions without cookies.

Comment: I'm afraid you are dead wrong on that. wordpress does not use sessions at all.

Comment: PHP cookies are part of PHP sessions - even if WP probably may not utilize server-side sessions for session data storage (in order to be compatible with some crappy shared hostings).

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that. In order to use sessions in php, you've got to enable sessions at the top of your page by using `session_start()` explicitly.  Now, obviously, wordpress does not have `session_start()` anywhere in its core. See where I'm getting confused by your last comment?

Comment: It's just basic principles of PHP sessions ...
that session_start() enables server-side storage whilst setcookie() enable client-side storage of session data.
Maybe just get rid of the idea that sessions and cookies are something completely different - the only real difference is the storage location.